# xlwings || excel visiblity issue

Tags: django, excel, xlwings

i am opening an excel with the help of xlwings for some computation and i have set the visible False but still user can see the excel is opened and also it takes time to open and do the required. i passed the data to a template via django and when page is refreshed it takes time to show the data which i don't want.  Is there any way to resolve this. below is my code for xlwings:

```
wb = xlwings.Book(r'\\FY 2019-20\DAILY REPORT\DAILY REPORT FORMAT.xlsx')
    xlwings.App().visible=False
    ws = wb.sheets['advance tracking sheet']
    dict1= {
    'C191' : 'J191',
    'C192' : 'J192',
    'C193' : 'J193',
    'C195' : 'J195',
    'C196' : 'J196',
    'C199' : 'J199',
    'C204' : 'J204',
    'C208' : 'J208',
    'C209' : 'J209',
    'C210' : 'J210',
    'C212' : 'J212',
    'C213' : 'J213',
    'C215' : 'J215',
    'C216' : 'J216',
    'C217' : 'J217',
    'C218' : 'J218',
    'C219' : 'J219',
    'C220' : 'J220',
    'C221' : 'J221',
    'C222' : 'J222',
    'C223' : 'J223',
    'C224' : 'J224',
    'C225' : 'J225',
    }
    yester_bal = []
    for i,j in dict1.items():
        b = ws.range(j). value
        c = b
        yester_bal.append(c)
```

Answer (score 0):

A `Book` is part of an `App`, so the correct way to go about this would be:

```
app = xlwings.App(visible=False)
wb = app.books.open(r'C:\path\to\myfile.xlsx')
```

Note that this will create a separate hidden instance of Excel.